# Value to switch

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

my code is working I just need a little help with revision. I am setting my bool

```
 public bool IsShowHelpMsg
    {
      get => _settingsService.IsShowHelpMsg;
      set
      {
        _settingsService.IsShowHelpMsg = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsShowHelpMsg");
      }
    }
```

Then I Have command when the switch is fired

```
ShowHelpMsgCommand = new Command<bool>((value) => ExecuteShowHelpMsgCommand(value));
```

Then the method

```
 private void ExecuteShowHelpMsgCommand(bool value)
    {
      NotifyPropertyChanged("IsShowHelpMsg");
    }
```

this works but if I have this in the Execute method  `_settingsService.IsShowHelpMsg = value;` it works too. I am just a bit confused as I don't know which way is correct or lets say more common. Please advise.

MY XAML

```
  <Label   Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.ShowHelpMsg_lbl}" Style="{StaticResource SubLabelStyle}"  HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                     <Switch HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="5" VerticalOptions="End" IsToggled="{Binding IsShowHelpMsg}" >
                         <Switch.Behaviors>
                             <control:SwitchBehaviour Command="{Binding ShowHelpMsgCommand}" />
                         </Switch.Behaviors>
                     </Switch>
```

My Settings Service

```
public bool IsShowHelpMsg
    {
        get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault("IsShowHelpMsg", true);
        set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue("IsShowHelpMsg", value);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your xaml? Is there any binding with IsShowHelpMsg?

Comment: is `_settingsService.IsShowHelpMsg` `true` by default? Otherwise this shouldn't be working since booleans are `false` by default.

Comment: Shared `Xaml and default is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is useless, since IsToggled is already bound to IsShowHelpMsg.
You can bind that property and convert it to Visibility to show/hide elements accordingly

Service

```
public bool IsShowHelpMsg
{
    get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault("IsShowHelpMsg", true);
    set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue("IsShowHelpMsg", value);
}
```

ViewModel

```
public bool IsShowHelpMsg {
    get => _service.IsShowHelpMsg;
    set
    {
        if(value == _service.IsShowHelpMsg) { return; }
        _service.IsShowHelpMsg = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsShowHelpMsg));
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Label Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.ShowHelpMsg_lbl}"
    Style="{StaticResource SubLabelStyle}"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    Padding="10"
    VerticalOptions="End" />

<Switch HorizontalOptions="End"
    Margin="5"
    VerticalOptions="End"
    IsToggled="{Binding IsShowHelpMsg}" />

<Label Text="Help message content"
    Visibility="{Binding IsShowHelpMsg,
        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is strange to me that your code works. Your ExecuteShowHelpMsgCommand method does not change IsShowHelpMsg now.

You should use in ExecuteShowHelpMsgCommand:

```
_settingsService.IsShowHelpMsg = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer this:

```
private void ExecuteShowHelpMsgCommand(bool value)
{
      IsShowHelpMsg = value;
}
```

It will set `_settingsService.IsShowHelpMsg` and also notify UI about changes.